# flex Error: unable to resolve resource bundle "core" for locale "en_US"

Tags: flex3, flowplayer

I'm trying to include a swc library in a flowplayer plugin I'm building, but when I include this swc it is referencing some of the core framework resource bundles.  But for some reason the mxmlc compiler is not finding them.

I've added the `-include-resource-bundles=core,effects,skins,styles` to the mxmlc arguments, but I'm still getting this error for each core, effects, etc:

```
Error: Unable to resolve resource bundle "core" for local "en_US".
```

I have the .properties files in my flexsdk folders.

Is there some other flag I'm missing for the mxmlc compiler to find these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a just an artifact of the flowplayer ant scripts, but I was able to solve this by including the path to the bundles explicitly in the `mxmlc_bin` call:

```
<arg line="-source-path @{src} ${mxmlc-library-path} ${mxmlc-sources} ${flex3dir}/frameworks/projects/framework/bundles/en_US/src" />
```